# prove the difference between mean and median is less than the variance

Tags: self-study, variance, mean, median, inequality

> Suppose $X$ is a random variable with finite variance. Let $m$ denote
> the median of $X$ and $\mu$ the mean of $X$, i.e. $\mu=\mathbb{E}(X)$.
> Show $$(m-\mu)^2\leq\text{var}(X)$$

Intuitively this is definitely correct, i.e. the median and mean can not be too far. How to show it? I was thinking of using Jensen's inequality on $\text{var}(X)=\mathbb{E}(X-\mu)^2$, but it does not work.

Comment: Here is a [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Inequality_relating_means_and_medians) from Wikipedia.